# Update offline status when no internet connection

Tags: android

I am implementing a VoIP service and users offline online status is managed at server end

**In My Coding part** 
 I have created online offline toggle this button will update the status of users who are *available/online* or who are *unavailable/offline*

Second, created calling button which will connect to other people using VoIP services.

***Assumptions :*** What if after I switch off my wifi since I am unavailable I can't update my status online so my status is online on server but in actual scenario I am offline.

User can connect or call me but since I am unavailable they will ring and wait for me to answer which is what happening in Whatsapp calling. If I am 
Unavailable it will ring and hung up after some time(Using **XMPP server**).

**What I want :** To update status on server before he gets disconnected from Internet. This will keep the status of all users correct with the actual state.

Comment: Better to use a time stamp on the server of the last time "seen" online. This time stamp is update every X minutes. If the time stamp is older than X+1, then the user is offline.

Comment: Buddy nice one but I don't have XMPP server I was telling that whatsapp have this server I am asking what can I do at my end if there is a way to send some before my internet is disconnected. I can't afford XMPP server neither my organisation can. :)

Comment: Usually in this kind of application you need to implement keep alive mechanism. Where client will send some KEEP_ALIVE message to server every min or some custom period. If Server is not receiving KEEP_ALIVE message server will consider that user as offline. Same on Receiver or client side to check if server is down(If needed)

Comment: OK this server is normal server i guess not some XMPP type. Well can you give some link how to implement it. I never heard of it.

Comment: I have used it with sockets where application sends byte containing 00 and server acknowledge it with 01. When there is no communication between two for more than 1 min, to tell server as application instance is alive and listening for incoming data. You may check implementation of SIP servers where it is commonly used. As mobile developer i don't have in depth knowledge of it

Comment: How can I send timestamp throughout my app active status when server stops receiving it. It switch the status to offline. Just tell me how to send timestamp on active activity status.

Comment: OK swapnil I'll try to do it.